# How to Add Custom Assets Toolbar Button in AEM -- base.jsp Overlay Not Working

Tags: jsp, aem, overlay, toolbar, assets

I am trying to add a custom button to my AEM Assets Toolbar to trigger a custom workflow instead of the default Delete workflow which I have been able to hide programatically.

I have created an overlay of /libs/dam/gui/coral/components/admin/contentrenderer/base/base.jsp to /apps/dam/gui/coral/components/admin/contentrenderer/base/base.jsp. Adding my modifications to the overlay base.jsp is not making any changes, however, when I add the same edit to the libs base.jsp file, my button will show up.

I am receiving no error messages with this, only that my custom button does not show up when I add it to the overlay file.

Is there a known problem with the /libs/dam/gui/coral/components/admin/contentrenderer/base/base.jsp overlay?

How can I properly overlay /libs/dam/gui/coral/components/admin/contentrenderer/base/base.jsp and actually make my changes?

Comment: I do not fully understand, what you try to reach. Could you provide a screenshot, and mark where you want to add a custom action? Creating an overlay for that file is 99% wrong.

Comment: How is creating an overlay wrong when you're not supposed to modify what's in libs?

Comment: I meant especially this very large JSP file is not meant to be overlayed. Doing it, could bring you in deep trouble in the long run. Very likely there is a better way to reach what you want to do. But what do you want to reach??

Comment: I'm trying to add custom buttons to the Toolbar of the Assets list page. For instance, we don't want to use the default Delete button but were looking into adding a custom Delete button to trigger a workflow. While we can train our content authors to use the Create Workflow option, we were looking at how to add a new button. The only information I could find about this online specifically said to overlay the base.jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

AEM generates most menus, toolbars, columns and dialogs from content structures. So it can be easy customized:

- to **hide** something for a certain user group, just revoke read-access for the corresponding content node
- to **add** something, create an additional node with the same parent path just under `/apps`, instead of `/libs` (overlay)

For the DAM it is under `/libs/dam/gui/content/assets/jcr:content/actions/selection`  (the action toolbar, if you select an asset inside the dam asset list)

[image]

A simple example would be **Lock (single asset)**, which is defined under `checkedoutenabled`. It defines the toolbar action, and important the `granite:class` property will be in the class-attribute of generated HTML-Button.

Then in `/libs/dam/gui/coral/components/admin/clientlibs/admin/js/drivelock.js` is an ordinary event handler for the button created - in `addButtonListener(...)`. It it just a little bit more complicated, as the function generically handles multiple actions (lock, unlock, ...). But I'm sure you find out how to create your own actions.

The JS file is part of a client-lib with the category `dam.gui.admin.coral`. All client-libs with this category a loaded by the DAM UI. So just create your own client-lib under `/apps/` with your custom event handler code.

kind regards,
Alex

Comment: Alex,

Thanks for your response. I do understand adding things to the selection area,  however, in my setup of 6.3, just adding an option under apps selection was not making the item show up. I had to add the custom class to be added appropriately in the base.jsp file, which wasn't overlaying at all.

In order to apply my solution, I had to overlay everything in the base folder and change the path to the includes in libs to pull from apps. It seems a bit convoluted from how things should work. We're hopefully upgrading in the next 2 months, so hopefully it won't be so difficult next time.